# Pushbutton Engine EventSoundTrigger

Tags: button, actionscript, push

I'm running into some issues using EventSoundTrigger in Pushbutton Engine

I am able to make it work using xml like this:

```
 <component type="com.pblabs.components.basic.EventSoundTrigger" name="Sounds">
     <startSound filename="/assets/explosion.mp3" />
   </component>
```

But if I try to write actionscript to do the same I throughs errors.  I can't find any examples online to explain how to initialize or use EventSoundTrigger directly in ActionScript.

The following throws an error that the sound object is null when the component is created.

I figured it out here's the answer:

```
   var et:EventSoundTrigger = new EventSoundTrigger();
    et.startSound = PBE.resourceManager.load("assets/noo.mp3", MP3Resource , onLoaded, onFailed) as MP3Resource ;
    var tEntity:IEntity = PBE.allocateEntity();
    tEntity.addComponent( et , "sound" ) ;
    tEntity.initialize("tsound");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when the EventSoundTrigger component is added to the entity, it needs that the startSound resource is ready. To do so, you could load the resource first and then create the component:

```
PBE.resourceManager.load("assets/02.mp3", MP3Resource, onLoaded, onFailed) as MP3Resource;

private function onLoaded(resource:MP3Resource):void
{
    var et:EventSoundTrigger = new EventSoundTrigger();
    et.startSound = resource;
    var tEntity:IEntity = PBE.allocateEntity();
    tEntity.addComponent( et , "sound" ) ;
    tEntity.deferring=false;
}
```